# PHP PDO fetch form data with while and foreach inside the while

Tags: php, pdo

I have trouble updating database from form that populate with select option.
This is my code to fill the update form with values from MSSQL database:

```
$result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT d.id as iddr, d.EGN, d.Names, d.NickName, d.Residence, d.PersonalMobilePhone, d.HomeAddress,d.GarantPerson, c.id as cid, c.city_name, c.post_code, t.id, t.IdDriver, t.StartDateVisa, t.EndDateVisa FROM paerp.dbo.Driver d FULL JOIN paerp.dbo.cities c ON d.Residence = c.id FULL JOIN dbo.TrVisas t ON d.id = t.IdDriver WHERE d.id = :id");

$result->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result->execute();
//for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
     while($row=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
?>
```

This is the select option place. This shows only the value from database. Without possibility to change from dropdown.

```
 <select id="residence" name="residence">
<option value="<?PHP echo $row['id']; ?>" selected><?PHP echo     $row['city_name']; ?></option>
<?PHP 
$result2 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, city_name, post_code FROM cities");
$result2->execute();
 while($row=$result2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
?>
    <option value="<?PHP echo $row['id']; ?>"><?PHP echo $row['city_name']; ?></option>     <?php
}
?>  
    </select>
```

I have more inputs after that select option but they are not filled with values from database. Everything stops to this dropdown.
Can sameone help me to figured it out the right way? Thank you!
I try with `foreach` in the place of the second `while` , but then the form inputs are populated but the dropdown do not work.

Comment: Is the first query expected to exactly one result? If it returns more, you will have some conflicts here - first that there will be unfetched rows possibly causing a "commands out of sync" error, and second, you use the same variable name `$row` for both fetch actions so the outer `while` loop will be overwritten inside.

Comment: Always when developing code, ensure PHP is displaying errors so we can see what else is failing. At the top of your code `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`. Also, setup your PDO connection to throw exceptions.  `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`  before using it to `prepare()` the first statement.

Comment: Michael Berkowski , your suggestion about the duplicate name `$row` fixed it, i change the name and now work fine. Thank you. How can i mark your oppinion for answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are executing two query `while` fetch loops, with one nested inside another. There may be other ways of organizing your logic, such as using `fetchAll()` to retrieve all rows from the outer query at once and then using a `foreach` to loop them.

But the main problem here is that you use the variable name `$row` in both fetch loops. This will cause the inner fetch to overwrite the previous contents of `$row`, breaking any future intended use of that array.  Simply using a different variable name than `$row` for the inner loop will help.

You may have been seeing PHP complain about unset array indexes that would have pointed more closely to problems with `$row`. Always when developing and testing code, ensure PHP is displaying errors on screen. At the top of your script, (or enable in php.ini on a development workstation):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

And ensure that PDO is throwing useful exceptions to help debug its behavior. By default it will error silently.

```
$pdo = new PDO(/* connection details... */);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```